# Magento SYSTEM backup

Tags: magento, backup, admin

I am trying to make a SYSTEM BACKUP (not database backup), i following the ordinary way (click on the system backup button on systems/tools/backups :3 ) but after waiting for a couple of minutes nothing happens: no success message, no line added to the backup list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please edit question with how many products, customers are there in database.  Its depends on how much size of your folders and database, wait for atleast 2-3 hours. also check var/logs folder. or you can try scheduled back up procedure.

**System > Configuration > Advanced > System > Scheduled Backup Settings**

```
Enable Scheduled Backup: Yes
 Backup Type: Database
 Start Time: 1:00 am
 Frequency: Daily
 Maintenance Mode: No
```

for scheduled backup you have to check cron job is working fine.